# How to treat a specif char as other value?

Tags: c++

Let's say that I receive the char 'R' I want to set that every time I will receive 'R' I will treat it as the value 5, what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: Depends.  Start with a `map`/`unordered_map` and go from there.

Comment: if it's only about `R` a simple `if(myChar == 'R') {...}` would do. A `map`/`unordered_map` is more expandable.

Answer (score 0):

As it is specific to `char`, you can use `array` of constant size.

Because of the following reasons:

- `char` range is limited. `-128 to 127 or 0 to 255`
- `char` and `int` are interoperable in C++.
- Array will give O(1) time complexity.

````cpp
// For example:

int array[256]; // ascii range is 0 to 255 in unsigned int form
// Set the value for char 'R'

array['R'] = 5;
// Ascii value of ```'R'``` is 82. It will be stored at index 82.

...
//Use array['R'] 
...
````

But if it is not `char` then [`std:map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or[`std:unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)  will be a better option

Comment: Re: -128 to 127 -- true on most systems, but this is not guaranteed by the language definition. There are systems with a much larger range of `char` values. But the issue isn't how many values a `char` can represent, it's how large a range the input might take on. That depends on the character encoding that's being used, and on most systems that will be ASCII, but, again, that's not required, and there are systems that use other encodings.